# What's the most up-to-date resource on the Israeli Foreign Affairs Union strike?

Tags: online-resources, israel, industrial-action

The Israeli consulate in SF [says the following](https://embassies.gov.il/san-francisco/ConsularServices/Pages/Passports-Travel-Documents.aspx):

> Due to sanctions by the Israeli Ministry of Foreign Affairs Workers Union, there is a restriction on some of the consular services given during this period. In addition, the Consulate General in San Francisco will not be able to issue passports until further notice.​

They provide a link to an [info page](https://embassies.gov.il/san-francisco/ConsularServices/Pages/UPDATE_PASSPORTS.aspx) but it hasn't been updated since July. What's the best resource (in Hebrew or English) to stay informed about when Israeli consulates might start issuing passports again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if the strike is officially over, but I just got a passport renewed at the embassy in DC

Comment: Same, passport was successfully extended. Only took 1 week.

Comment: They did mine on the spot.

Answer (score 5):

[This](https://embassies.gov.il/san-francisco/ConsularServices/Pages/UPDATE_PASSPORTS.aspx) is the best resource. Currently they don't plan on issuing passports before January 1st.

Israel is currently preparing for the elections on November 1st, and the new government will probably not be sworn in before November ends. The elections were announced end of June, which is why the last update is dated in July. The current MoFA is also the Israeli PM and is understandably more busy with being reelected than figuring out the strike. I don't see any reason to think that the strike will end before the currently stated January 1st target date.

---

Updating as of Dec'22: the webpage with the information about the strike is now gone, and the Israeli Consulate in SF is now issuing passports again (verified). There was no announcement on the strike ending, but it has seemingly ended.

Comment: Looks like the strike is over? The consulate does issue passports again but I can't find a confirmation that the strike is officially concluded.