# Is passport issuance within Israel affected by the Foreign Ministry strike?

Tags: passports, israel

There’s currently a strike of Ministry of Foreign Affairs employees which makes it impossible to extend Israeli passports at consulates. Does this strike also affect the issuance of passports within Israel as well? Or should one expect to be able to get a biometric passport within the normal ~3 weeks timeline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, passports in Israel are issued by the Ministry of Interior. The timeline may be affected by the [Ministry of the Interior being swamped with passport requests and lack of appointment slots](https://www.ynet.co.il/economy/article/bydnxrzdc#autoplay), though. I doubt you can turn this around in 3 weeks (if you intend to visit Israel for the purpose of passport renewal).

You may be able to get an emergency 1-yr passport at the airport on the spot, costs double the price.

Until the end of this year, Israelis who have foreign passports are allowed to use their foreign passports to enter and leave the country (see the announcement at the Israeli consulate in SF web page I linked to in [the other answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/177060/1295)).

Comment: Do you know what a realistic turn around time would be currently?

Comment: @JonathanReez I think once you got to your appointment then 3-4 weeks is realistic, it's just appointments are scarce.

Comment: You should be able to get an appointment in two months (varies by place and time), then add six weeks for mailing the passport (it actually took 6 weeks for a relative's passport recently)