# Can one keep one's current Israeli passport while an extension application is pending?

Tags: passports, israel

Given the current [consular employees strike](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/177058/whats-the-most-up-to-date-resource-on-the-israeli-foreign-affairs-union-strike), one cannot extend one's passport at Israeli consulates. Doing so in Israel [apparently takes 6 weeks](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/177061/is-passport-issuance-within-israel-affected-by-the-foreign-ministry-strike?noredirect=1&lq=1). Given the exception circumstances, is it possible to arrive to Israel, submit a passport application and then leave the country on one's current passport?

The question is for a relative who does not possess a second passport and needs a valid Israeli one urgently for bureaucratic reasons in a different country.

Comment: The "exception circumstances" have to be one of the exceptions listed [here](https://www.gov.il/en/departments/alerts/temporary_traveling_document_issuing), which in your case may not be valid

Comment: @littleadv do these requirements apply only at Ben Gurion or also at normal passport offices?

Comment: These are for the emergency passport (as the answer suggests,  you can also apply for it at the normal passport offices, and at the dedicated passport office in Bnei Brak)

Answer (score 4):

No. What you can do, is apply for a temporary passport together with your application for a permanent passport. The temporary passport is ready in 2 days. In order to be eligible for one, you must show a flight ticket booked in your name that leaves in less than 6 weeks.

If 2 days is too much for you to wait, you can get a temporary passport on the spot at Ben Gurion Airport. There it costs more and you need a plane ticket in your name for the next 48 hours.

Comment: Note that you can only do that once, you cannot get another temporary passport unless you renewed your passport *in Israel*.